# Pick randomly index of samples in dataset

Tags: python, random

I ve got in python a dataset of 31 samples. I want to split it the datasett randomly 30 times in 30 training samples and 1 samples test samples, how can I do so?

Right now I just split using the first 30 for training and the last one for testing like this:

> training_this_round = training[0:30]
>
> testing_this_round =training[30:31]

How can I pick the rows of the matrix randomly? Training is the variable which contain all my initial dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) for this kind of thing.

Let's create a dummy dataset with 31 samples (we'll say they're integers):

```
training = range(31)
```

Now we can use `shuffle` to divide this set up into two random subgroups:

```
import random
# copy training to preserve the order of the original dataset
this_round = training[:]
# permute the elements
random.shuffle(this_round)
# separate into training and test
training_this_round = this_round[:30]
testing_this_round = this_round[30:31]
```

Essentially, this puts the samples in random order (just like shuffling a deck of cards), and then takes the top card for testing, and uses the rest for training.  The thing I like about this is that it extends to other kinds of splits (e.g., deal the top 3 cards off into the test set, then deal off another 5 into a validation set, and take the rest for training).

Because you're only using a single sample for testing, it's also easy to do things the other way around, by picking a card (sample) at random, and removing it from the deck:

```
# pick an index into training at random
select = random.randint(0, len(training) - 1)
# test set is a single sample (not a list)
testing_this_round = training[select]
# training set is all elements except the one chosen for testing
training_this_round = [x for (i, x) in enumerate(training) if i != select]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, how can I keep the index of the testing_round?

Comment: Also the index variable training is kind of misleading since training is the name of my initial dataset.

Comment: Does the last edit help towards "keeping the index" of the training round?  You could remember the value of `select` in that case.  Also, I'm not using `training` as an index variable, I'm intending it to be a dataset (in the answer, it's a dummy dataset consisting of a bunch of integer values).

Answer (score 2):

Third-party array toolkits like `numpy` would make the following much easier to manage without error, and third-party machine-learning packages like `scikit-learn` already have higher-level solutions to the problem of cross-validation.  But assuming we take your question at face value and do everything by hand and on foot, here's an approach that should work:

```
import random

indices = list(range(len(dataset)))
random.shuffle(indices)  # shuffle just once before folding: this ensures we don't re-use any test fold indices

validation_results = []
leave_n_out = 1
for test_start in range(0, len(indices), leave_n_out):  # work through the different folds of the cross-validation
    test_stop = test_start + leave_n_out

    testing_this_round  = [dataset[i] for i in indices[test_start:test_stop]]
    training_this_round = [dataset[i] for i in indices[:test_start] + indices[test_stop:]]

    model = train(training_this_round)  # whatever that involves
    validation_results.append( test(model, testing_this_round) ) # whatever that involves
```